# Firebase not sending notification when the app is running?

Tags: android, firebase, android-webview

I've searched the questions here, but all I found is about a problem when the app is NOT running.

In my case, after I sent a text notification from Firebase Console - the App receive the notification when :

1. The App is killed (not running at all)
2. The App is in the background (but not open / hiding).
3. The App is open, but the cellphone screen itself is in the condition "off". (I have to click the hard button to make the screen light again, and then swipe it to see this App which is being open).

My question is :
If the App is open (the screen is on and while the App is active - I touch touch the screen in order not to let the screen goes off), is it normal that I won't receive the notification ?

Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

Push Notification in Firebase:

When your app is killed and in background your `onMessageReceived` method will not be called. Your notification will be in system tray according to docs. You can retrieve your notification from your default launcher class.

```
<application
    android:name=".AppController"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".view.SplashScreen">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

My launcher class is Splashscreen, when the app is killed, you can retrieve notification data from the bundle.

SplashScreen.Java

```
public class SplashScreen extends AppCompatActivity {
    String messageBody, notificationtype, id, title;
    Context mContext;

/**
 * Called when the activity is first created.
 */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);

    mContext = SplashScreen.this;
    if (getIntent().getExtras() != null && this.getIntent().getExtras().containsKey("title")) {

        Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
        String someData = b.getString("title");
        String id = b.getString("id");
        String notificationtype = b.getString("notification_type");
        String message = b.getString("message");
        //   Log.e("firebaseid", id);
        //    Log.e("firebase", someData);
        //   Log.e("firebase", notificationtype);
        Intent i = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, NotificationMessage.class);
        i.putExtra("title", someData);
        i.putExtra("id", id);
        i.putExtra("notificationtype", notificationtype);
        i.putExtra("messageBody", message);
        startActivity(i);
        finish();
    } 
}
```

When your app is active and foreground you will receive the push notification your `onMessageReceieved` will be called.

MyFirebaseMessagingService.Java

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseMsgService";

    String notificationtype, id, title, message, messagebody;


@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    //Displaying data in log

  //  String message = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody().toString();
     messagebody = remoteMessage.getData().toString();

 //   sendNotification(message);


      notificationtype=remoteMessage.getData().get("notification_type");


    id=remoteMessage.getData().get("id");
    title=remoteMessage.getData().get("title");
    message=remoteMessage.getData().get("message");
}

private void showNotification(String messageBody, String notificationtype, String title, String id) {

}
```

Comment: Hi Pradeep, thank you for your kind reply. Actually I even still need to know what exactly about App in foreground VS App in background. First I thought that "App in foreground" is : the App is being used by the user.... it's open and the user is "playing" on the App. "App in background" is : the App is not being used, but the App is still in the "recently open program" list in the Android phone. "App is killed" is : the App which reside in "recently open program" is cleared by the user.

Comment: But it seems I was wrong. It seems that "App in backround" is : the App is not open and also is not in the "recently open program BUT the service still running. For example WhatsApp. Even if WA is not currently being used by the user and also is not in the "recently open program" but the WA service is still running in the background. That's why we can receive a notification if there is a message coming. While "WA is killed" is that we "force stop" WA... so WA is not available at all, and won't show notification when somebody send a message. Am I correct ?

Comment: Firebase service won't be called when u killed the App and the Firebase service won't be running ,when the app is killed.When the app is opened again,the Firebase Service would be called.

Comment: Would you please explain to me, is "killed application"  =  "force stop the application" ? In other words, to kill the app - I need to do these steps : go to application manager ---> choose the app to be killed ---> then click the Force Stop button. Thank you pradeep.

Comment: Yeah, "killed application" = "force stop the application is the same way.

Comment: Thank you pradeep.